# How can I scroll the scrollbar of a fixed size in Android?

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

How can I scroll the scrollbar in my `listView` of a fixed size like 40px in my Android application?

Answer (score 0):

Try provding the listView attributes like this,

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fillparent"
android:layout_height="40dip"/>
```

This will make your listview to occupy only the height specified in the height attribute and as of which you can get your scroll for 40px alone.

Comment: but i have more element in my list and the dimension of the single element is 40px, i want to see only one element at a time

Comment: Since you provide height as 40px it doesn't mean that you can't view other data in listview. You can scroll listview further to see the next element but your listview totally will occupy only 40px height in the layout.